# Can i change the buttons in firefox to look like in macOS?

Tags: gnome, unity, firefox, themes

I have ubuntu 22.04 and want to change the buttons theme to look like MacOS could you help me to fix this issue?

current setting: [image]

What I want:

[image]

I installed gnome themes but it changed only icons in my applications for example in discord but firefox is still default.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of "pleasures" of snap packages. Theme must be packed in snap package too and connected to firefox package.
For example:

```
sudo snap install numix-gtk-themes
sudo snap connect firefox:gtk-3-themes numix-gtk-themes:gtk-3-theme
```

There's `gtk-common-themes` package with a bunch of themes, but, I presume, it doesn't contain your theme.